# Pytorch split Tensor when consecutive zeros

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, tensor

I am attempting to segment a 1D pytorch tensor each time when a sequence of x consecutive zeros is encountered. If additional zero elements follow this 'split,' I intend to remove them until the next non-zero value. Currently, I'm employing a for-loop over the zero indices to achieve this. However, this approach is slow, especially when dealing with large tensors containing numerous zero values. Do you have any suggestions on how I can enhance and optimize this code, possibly using PyTorch-specific functions for improved performance?

My tensors here have 2 dims, but the first dim doesnt matter for this task (ignore it).

```
def _split_tensor_gpu(split_flow, consecutive_zeros):
 zero_indices = torch.nonzero(split_flow[:, 1] == 0).view(-1)

 if len(zero_indices) == 0:
     return [split_flow]

 splitted_list = []
 first_index = 0
 zero_counter = 0

 for i in range(1, len(zero_indices)):
    if zero_indices[i] - zero_indices[i - 1] == 1:
        zero_counter += 1
    else:
        zero_counter = 0

    if zero_counter == consecutive_zeros:
        splitted_list.append(split_flow[first_index:zero_indices[i]])
        first_index = zero_indices[i] + 1

    if zero_counter > consecutive_zeros:
        first_index = zero_indices[i] + 1

 if first_index <= len(split_flow) - 1:
    splitted_list.append(split_flow[first_index:])

 return splitted_list
```

Solution:
Based on the first comment, which did most of the job but didn't remove the zeros after splitting, I adapted the function and got the following (this should do the job now):

```
def _split_tensor_gpu2(tensor_, consecutive_zeros):
    # step 1: identify Zero Sequences
    # create a mask of zeros and find the difference between consecutive elements
    is_zero = tensor_[:, 1] == 0
    diff = torch.diff(is_zero.float(), prepend=torch.tensor([0.0], device=tensor_.device))

    # start and end indices of zero sequences
    start_indices = torch.where(diff == 1)[0]
    end_indices = torch.where(diff == -1)[0]

    # adjust for cases where sequences reach the end of the tensor
    if len(end_indices) == 0 or (len(start_indices) > 0 and end_indices[-1] < start_indices[-1]):
        end_indices = torch.cat([end_indices, tensor_.size(0) * torch.ones(1, dtype=torch.long, device=tensor_.device)])

    # step 2: mark split points
    # find sequences with length >= consecutive_zeros
    valid_seqs = (end_indices - start_indices) > consecutive_zeros
    valid_start_indices = start_indices[valid_seqs] + consecutive_zeros  # 0:st+2
    valid_end_indices = end_indices[valid_seqs]

    splits = []
    end_idx = 0
    for i in range(len(valid_start_indices)):
        splits.append(tensor_[end_idx:valid_start_indices[i]])
        end_idx = valid_end_indices[i]

    # add the remaining part of the tensor if any
    if end_idx < tensor_.size(0):
        splits.append(tensor_[end_idx:])

    return splits
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PyTorch's built-in functions on tensor-related operations:

```
import torch

def _split_tensor_gpu(tensor, consecutive_zeros):

    # step 1: identify Zero Sequences
    # create a mask of zeros and find the difference between consecutive elements
    is_zero = tensor[:, 1] == 0
    diff = torch.diff(is_zero.float(), prepend=torch.tensor([0.0], device=tensor.device))

    # start and end indices of zero sequences
    start_indices = torch.where(diff == 1)[0]
    end_indices = torch.where(diff == -1)[0]

    # adjust for cases where sequences reach the end of the tensor
    if len(end_indices) == 0 or (len(start_indices) > 0 and end_indices[-1] < start_indices[-1]):
        end_indices = torch.cat([end_indices, tensor.size(0) * torch.ones(1, dtype=torch.long, device=tensor.device)])

    # step 2: mark split points
    # find sequences with length >= consecutive_zeros
    valid_seqs = (end_indices - start_indices) >= consecutive_zeros
    valid_start_indices = start_indices[valid_seqs]
    valid_end_indices = end_indices[valid_seqs]

    # step 3: split the tensor
    # split the tensor at valid indices
    splits = []
    start_idx = 0
    for end_idx in valid_end_indices:
        splits.append(tensor[start_idx:end_idx])
        start_idx = end_idx

    # add the remaining part of the tensor if any
    if start_idx < tensor.size(0):
        splits.append(tensor[start_idx:])

    return splits

# Example usage
tensor = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=torch.float32).t()
consecutive_zeros = 3
split_tensors = _split_tensor_gpu(tensor, consecutive_zeros)
```

Comment: It mostly does the job thanks! One thing is missing tho - the zeros should be deleted of consecutive zeros is reached. But i should be able to do that^^